# How to compile non-common language in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake, futhark

I am trying to switch from Makefile to CMake for one of my projects. The issue is that in the compilation steps, I use a non-common language compiler (Futhark) to generate a .c and .h file. The relevant part of the Makefile looks like this.

```
fut_compile: futhark/select_where.fut
  mkdir -p build && futhark c --library futhark/select_where.fut -o build/select_where

fut_shared_lib: build/select_where.c build/select_where.h
  gcc build/select_where.c -o build/lib_select_where.so -fPIC -shared

# Generate output directory
fut_result: build/lib_select_where.so db_gpu_load.cpp CLI.cpp
  g++ -std=c++11 build/lib_select_where.so db_gpu_load.cpp CLI.cpp -o build/out
```

I imagine that the CMake file would look something like this:

```
# ??
# ?? futhark c --library futhark/select_where.fut -o build/select_where
# ??

add_library(mylib SHARED
   build/select_where.c
   build/lib_select_where.so
)

add_executable(Exe CLI.cpp  db_gpu_load.cpp)

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Exe LINK_PUBLIC mylib)
```

Is there a standard why to add compilation of a non-standard language that generates a source and header files, and then include these files when generating a shared library in CMake? I am very new to CMake, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `add_custom_command` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it like this:

```
// build/select_where.c build/select_where.h: futhark/select_where.fut
//  mkdir -p build && futhark c --library futhark/select_where.fut -o build/select_where
add_custom_command(
     OUTPUT
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/select_where.c
         ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/select_where.h
     COMMAND futhark c 
         --library futhark/select_where.fut 
         -o ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/select_where
     DEPENDS futhark/select_where.fut
     WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
     VERBATIM
)

// build/lib_select_where.so: build/select_where.c build/select_where.h
//    gcc build/select_where.c -o build/lib_select_where.so -fPIC -shared
add_library(select_where SHARED
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/select_where.c
   ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/select_where.h
)
// maybe target_include_diresctories(select_where PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
// so that selct_where.h is visible, dunno

// build/out: build/lib_select_where.so db_gpu_load.cpp CLI.cpp
//    g++ -std=c++11 build/lib_select_where.so db_gpu_load.cpp CLI.cpp -o build/out
add_executable(out 
    db_gpu_load.cpp
    CLI.cpp
)
target_link_libraries(out PRIVATE
    select_where
)
set_target_properties(out PROPERTIES
    CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD            CXX11
    CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED   TRUE
)
```

Comment: This works! I appreciate the help. Is there a reason add_custom_command target is used instead of execute_process, or are they interchangeable in this case?

Comment: `cmake` does __not__ build your project. `cmake` configures the tool (make, nmake, ninja, etc.) that in turn _will_ build the project. So there are two stages - configuration part when cmake is run, and the build part when the other utility is run. `execute_process` runs with cmake on configuring stage, and it runs without dependencies. `custom_command` runs on build stage and check the timestamps of dependencies before regenretaing.

Answer (score 1):

You could use CMake's [`execute_process`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/execute_process.html) command to run `futhark` and generate the `.c` and `.h` files at the CMake configuration stage. This way, the files are available for use in later CMake commands, such as `add_library()`:

```
# Generate the .c and .h files into the current CMake binary directory.
execute_process(COMMAND 
    futhark c --library ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/futhark/select_where.fut -o select_where
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
)

# Reference the generated .c when specifying the lib_select_where library target.
add_library(lib_select_where SHARED
    ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/select_where.c
)

# Use the generated .h when compiling this, by adding its location as an include directory.
target_include_directories(lib_select_where PRIVATE ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
# Add the -fPIC compile option.
target_compile_options(lib_select_where PRIVATE -fPIC)
```